# Generate a new factor variable based on the presence or missing of observations of different date variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stata

I have the following data

**R code**

```
df <- data.frame(idnum = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004),
             date1 = c(2003-03-19, 2003-03-19, 2003-03-19, 2003-03-19),
             date2 = c(2004-03-24, NA, 2004-03-25, 2004-03-26),
             date3 = c(2005-05-11, 2005-05-12, 2005-05-12, NA))
```

and would like to do something like the following I did in Stata

**Stata code**

```
gen xvisit=1 if date1 !=. & date2 !=. & date3!=.
replace xvisit=2 if date1 !=. & date2 !=. & date3 ==. 
replace xvisit=3 if date1 !=. & date2 ==. & date3 !=.
replace xvisit=4 if date1 !=. & date2 ==. & date3 ==.
label define xvisit 1 "All" 2 "Baseline & 2nd" 3 "Baseline & 3rd" 4 "Baseline only"
label values xvisit xvisit
```

But i just can't get it right in R.
My aim is to get something like

```
Stata Output
```

enter image desc[image]ription here

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please make sure sample data you provide in questions is legal R code. While this is not a syntax error, I tend to doubt that you want `date2` to be a numeric column with values `c(1977, NA, 1976, 1975)` (i.e., `2004` minus `3` minus `24`, etc). And yes, please indicate your expected output given this input. Thanks!

Comment: It's Stata code @r2evans

Comment: STATA uses `df <- data.frame(...)` and `c(...)` as well? Sorry, I didn't know that, my bad.

Comment: I guess what @r2evans is hinting is that R won't read 2003-03-19 as a date, only as an expression with numeric result.

Comment: @r2evans Only the second block of code is Stata.

Comment: @NickCox, **yes**, I get that. Perhaps my point was vague, so I'll be clear: while it's easy for us to fix code that is "obviously wrong" in a sense (typos because we're getting code that is not really being used anywhere), it can be unclear if the OP is actually using that code as-is. That is, is @Peace assigning `somedate <- 2021-02-24` and expecting it to be a `Date` object? It is the obligation of the OP to make sure the code works and generates relevant objects. There is obviously wiggle-room for us to fill in blanks, but in general it is preferred if the OP does that before "submit".

Comment: Questions that require bilingual fluency (my level: Stata experienced, R very occasional) are often harder than just saying what you want in English. Here a variable is 1 if three dates are non-missing and 2, 3, 4 if respectively the 3rd, 2nd, 1st date is missing. (So: what if two dates are missing? what if all three dates are missing?  I can't speak for how the OP intends to hold those dates in R or whether the R code is legal and/or corrrect.

Comment: @r2evans I am agreeing with you, so no need to go bold here.

Comment: I went bold because it seemed clear to me in your *"second block .. is Stata"* comment that my comment was not clear. Now that I've reread it a few times (anew), I see now how my first comment was unclear: I should have said *"legal R code in the R code block"*. I had clarity which was which and was commenting on and referencing only one nlock, but I see how that might be misconstrued. Thanks all.

Comment: My aim is to tabulate xvisit as a 4 category/levels variable showing frequencies by set condition per category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using `within`. In R we begin to initialize the xvisit column with `NA`. To look up row-wise where all dates are missing we can efficiently use the `rowSums` of the negated `is.na` check—when it's `3` we got it. The other lines should be self-explanatory. At the end we create a `factor` with `levels=` corresponding to the numerical values and `labels=` in the order of the levels.

You may also want to consider to  convert your character dates into date format using `as.Date` beforehand.

```
df[c("date1", "date2", "date3")] <- lapply(df[c("date1", "date2", "date3")], as.Date)

df <- within(df, {
  xvisit <- NA
  xvisit[rowSums(!is.na(df[c("date1", "date2", "date3")])) == 3] <- 1
  xvisit[is.na(df[["date3"]])] <- 2
  xvisit[is.na(df[["date2"]])] <- 3
  xvisit[is.na(df[["date1"]])] <- 4
  xvisit <- factor(xvisit, levels=1:4, 
                   labels=c("All", "Baseline & 2nd", "Baseline & 3rd", "Baseline only"))
})
df
#   idnum      date1      date2      date3         xvisit
# 1  1001 2003-03-19 2004-03-24 2005-05-11            All
# 2  1002 2003-03-19       <NA> 2005-05-12 Baseline & 3rd
# 3  1003 2003-03-19 2004-03-25 2005-05-12            All
# 4  1004 2003-03-19 2004-03-26       <NA> Baseline & 2nd
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(idnum = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004), date1 = c("2003-03-19", 
"2003-03-19", "2003-03-19", "2003-03-19"), date2 = c("2004-03-24", 
NA, "2004-03-25", "2004-03-26"), date3 = c("2005-05-11", "2005-05-12", 
"2005-05-12", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```